# UNPIVOT in sql server with two input values (converting from Oracle to sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

in Oracle I have written a statement where I use UNPIVOT. That part looks like this:

```
unpivot ((value, prev_value) for col in ( 
(title, prev_title)      as 'title'                                                              , (stage, prev_stage)    as 'stage'                                                              , (value, prev_value)    as 'value'
```

Till now I am not able to find a way of doing the same with sql server. Any suggestionsl

Answer (score 4):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT other_column1,
       other_column2,
       'title' AS col,
       title AS value,
       prev_title AS prev_value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  title IS NOT NULL
AND    prev_title IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT other_column1,
       other_column2,
       'stage' AS col,
       stage AS value,
       prev_stage AS prev_value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  stage IS NOT NULL
AND    prev_stage IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT other_column1,
       other_column2,
       'value' AS col,
       value,
       prev_value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  value IS NOT NULL
AND    prev_value IS NOT NULL
```

or, as suggested by [@MartinSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74276057/unpivot-in-sql-server-with-two-input-values-converting-from-oracle-to-sql-serve/74276572?noredirect=1#comment131133853_74276572), use `CROSS APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT other_column1,
       other_column2,
       v.col,
       v.value,
       v.prev_value
FROM   table_name
       CROSS APPLY
       (values  (title, prev_title, 'title'), 
                (stage, prev_stage, 'stage'), 
                (value, prev_value, 'value')
       ) v(value, prev_value, col)
WHERE  v.prev_value IS NOT NULL
AND    v.col IS NOT NULL
```

[SQL Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qVZhZQEy) - [Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/70qT1axq)

Comment: `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` would be more concise and more efficient https://dbfiddle.uk/UBKcQsEV

Comment: Yes, for now I think CROSS APPLY will be cleaner for me if the list gets longer. Thanks both for the help.